# Is there an equivalent to Java's \p{Punct} in Haxe regexes?

Tags: java, regex, haxe

Haxe's manual has no regex symbol detail. I can't find which symbol maps to Java's `\p{Punct}`.

Does Haxe have anything similar?

Comment: Nothing is said about shorthand classes support in the documentation. Looks like you need to specify the punctuation you need inside a character class, like `[.,?;:"']`....

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to the [documentation](http://haxe.org/manual/std-regex-implementation-details.html), the punctuation unicode character class seems to be only available when you use PCRE (Neko, C++, PHP) and for Java and C#. Whatever, you can try different syntaxes with or without an escaped backslash: `\p{Punct}` `\p{P}` `\pP` and eventually the POSIX character class: `[[:punct:]]`

These classes are not available for JavaScript (and probably not for Flash either). In this case the way is to put all punctuation characters in a class using ranges as most as possible.